# Start processing Flux response from server before completion: is it possible?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, openapi, openapi-generator

I have 2 Spring-Boot-Reactive apps, one server and one client; the client calls the server like so:

```java
Flux<Thing> things = thingsApi.listThings(5);
```

And I want to have this as a list for later use:

```java
// "extractContent" operation takes 1.5s per "thing"
List<String> thingsContent = things.map(ThingConverter::extractContent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .block()
```

On the server side, the endpoint definition looks like this:

```java
@Override
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<Thing>>> listThings(
        @NotNull @Valid @RequestParam(value = "nbThings") Integer nbThings,
        ServerWebExchange exchange
) {
    // "getThings" operation takes 1.5s per "thing"
    Flux<Thing> things = thingsService.getThings(nbThings);
    return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(things, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

The signature comes from the Open-API generated code (Spring-Boot server, reactive mode).

---

**What I observe:** the client jumps to `things.map` immediately but only starts processing the `Flux` after the server has finished sending all the "things".

**What I would like:** the server should send the "things" *as they are generated* so that the client can start processing them *as they arrive*, effectively halving the processing time.

Is there a way to achieve this? I've found many tutorials online for the server part, but none with a java client. I've heard of server-sent events, but can my goal be achieved using a "classic" Open-API endpoint definition that returns a `Flux`?

The problem seemed too complex to fit a minimal viable example in the question body; full code available for reference [on Github](https://github.com/Erkenbend/spring-reactive-api).

EDIT: redirect link to `main` branch after merge of the proposed solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it running by changing 2 points:

- First: I've changed the `content` type of the response of your `/things` endpoint, to:

```
content:
  text/event-stream
```

Don't forget to change also the default response, else the client will expect the type `application/json` and will wait for the whole response.

- Second point: I've changed the return of `ThingsService.getThings` to `this.getThingsFromExistingStream` (the method you comment out)

I pushed my changes to a new branch `fix-flux-response` on your Github, so you can test them directly.

Comment: some comments on your code, you dont have to return a `Mono<ResponseEntity>` if you just return `Flux<T>` from your controller method, then the framework will wrap it for you. If you on the other hand really want to return custom response (say another status code etc) look into the `ServerResponse` builder class that will build `Mono<ServerResponse>` for you.

Comment: also, why you had a hard time using curl is that curl buffers responses, so when you do a request, curl doesn\t print everything in its buffer until the connection against the server its calling is closed. So if you want to `stream` the response you need disable buffering with the `-N/--no-buffer` flag. `curl -N localhost:8081/things`

Comment: @Toerktumlare I get your comment on cURL but how to keep Spring Boot happy while changing the signature of my endpoint method? When I simply change it to `Flux<Thing>`, the class does not implement the interface anymore...
EDIT: it seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/7566)

Comment: I have never used OpenAPI so that must be an issue on their end